# Bean cannot be found unless it is in upper package

Tags: java, spring-boot, temporal

I have a temporal activity class under package

```
com.x.nl.y.customercare.processes.activity.subscription
```

Class looks like

```
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class ServiceActivitiesImpl implements ServiceActivities {
    private final Service service;

    @Override
    public canBeSavedResponse canBeSaved(CanBeSavedRequest request) {
        return service.canBeSaved(request);
    }
}
```

The injected Service bean class is under the package

```
com.x.nl.y.customercare.service
```

The issue is Spring cannot inject this service bean into activity due to

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.x.nl.y.customercare.service.Service'
```

But if I move it into `com.x.nl.y.customercare.processes` or any subpackage of it then it works.

What's wrong with the service package ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me this is an due to incorrect component scanning. Your application is only scanning beans defined in `com.x.nl.y.customercare.processes` package.

Make sure that `@ComponentScan` or `@SpringBootApplication` annotation on you main application class includes the package `com.x.nl.y.customercare.service` as well, otherwise spring won't detect it.

```
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {
        "com.x.nl.y.customercare.processes",
        "com.x.nl.y.customercare.service"
    }
)
```

or using `@SpringBootApplication`

```
@SpringBootApplication(
    scanBasePackages = {
        "com.x.nl.y.customercare.processes",
        "com.x.nl.y.customercare.service"
    }
)
```

or you can simply put `com.x.nl.y.customercare` to include both the packages.

This can also occur if your main application class is under `com.x.nl.y.customercare.processes` package which by default only scan packages within `processes` for any bean definitions.

Answer (score -2):

are you missing @Autowired ?
spring scans packages looking for specific annotations. maybe the service is in a package out of the default scope

Comment: The `lombok.AllArgsConstructor` creates a Constructor with needed var definition and Spring does all it's magic from the constructor itself. That's why `@Autowired` is not needed here

Comment: See reference [here](https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/04/core-container-refinements-in-spring-framework-4-3)